# Pass object into helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm using rails 3.2.11 and trying to pass an object into a custom helper from a view and I don't understand why this works:

```
- @data = { name: "Add Skus", f: f, container: "skus", association: :skus, child_association: :images, options: @sku_options }
= link_to_add_fields @data
```

but this doesn't:

```
= link_to_add_fields { name: "Add Skus", f: f, container: "skus", association: :skus, child_association: :images, options: @sku_options }
```

I get the error: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'`

**Helper method:**

```
def link_to_add_fields(data)
  STDOUT << "name: " + data[:name].to_s + " :: "
  STDOUT << "f.object: " + data[:f].object.to_s + " :: "
  STDOUT << "association: " + data[:association].to_s + " :: "
  STDOUT << "container: " + data[:container].to_s + " :: "

  if data[:child_association]
    STDOUT << "child_association: " + data[:child_association].to_s + " :: "
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, Ruby thinks you're passing in a block as a parameter due to the braces. Add parentheses around your options, or get rid of the braces:

```
= link_to_add_fields({name: "Add Skus", f: f, container: "skus", association: :skus, child_association: :images, options: @sku_options})
```

or

```
= link_to_add_fields name: "Add Skus", f: f, container: "skus", association: :skus, child_association: :images, options: @sku_options
```